# Visual Studio Code not showing warnings in problems-tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, warnings

I hid my warnings in the problems-tab of VSC. Now I cannot remember where I did this from, so I don't know how to recover the warning signs. For the moment, no warnings are displayed in any case, even if I run absolutely nonsense code.

How can I recover the warnings of the problems tab? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is it but you can check the "Show Warnings" in Problems tab just like this.
[image]